# Cancelling of a future task does not work with ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I simply want to cancel a future task that was submitted in a "ForkJoinPool"-ThreadPool.

```
Future<?> startedFuture = myforkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
   //long living task
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        // do some break operation
    }
}
```

Another thread is calling

```
startedFuture.cancel(true)
```

return value is true, so it seams to be ok, 
AND nothing happens!

**BUT**: I just change the Threadpool instance into a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` for example,
the cancel event will be performed correctly and I will get the expected InterruptedException.
The futureTask-Thread is interrupted like expected.

Are there restrictions in using the ForkJoinPool or any options to have the same behavior for the cancel-operation like the other ThreadPool?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the ForkJoinPool does not support cancelation. From the documentation of java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask#cancel

```
    /**
     * Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will
     * fail if the task has already completed or could not be
     * cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task
     * has not started when {@code cancel} is called, execution of
     * this task is suppressed. After this method returns
     * successfully, unless there is an intervening call to {@link
     * #reinitialize}, subsequent calls to {@link #isCancelled},
     * {@link #isDone}, and {@code cancel} will return {@code true}
     * and calls to {@link #join} and related methods will result in
     * {@code CancellationException}.
     *
     * <p>This method may be overridden in subclasses, but if so, must
     * still ensure that these properties hold. In particular, the
     * {@code cancel} method itself must not throw exceptions.
     *
     * <p>This method is designed to be invoked by <em>other</em>
     * tasks. To terminate the current task, you can just return or
     * throw an unchecked exception from its computation method, or
     * invoke {@link #completeExceptionally(Throwable)}.
     *
     * @param mayInterruptIfRunning this value has no effect in the
     * default implementation because interrupts are not used to
     * control cancellation.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if this task is now cancelled
     */
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        int s = abnormalCompletion(DONE | ABNORMAL);
        return (s & (ABNORMAL | THROWN)) == ABNORMAL;
    }
```